# Formatting and bullet points

Tags: lists, itemize, block

Sorry for what may seem like a basic question. I've created a poster using a template, and have created bullet point lists inside various blocks. Within one of the blocks, the bullet points fall outside of the block itself, whilst in all other blocks the bullet points are inside.

I have looked at the code extensively, as has a member of staff at writelatex, but unfortunately neither of us are able to spot what the problem is. There does not appear to be a difference in the code from any of the other blocks.

This is the code;

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster with a portrait orientation and an a0 paper size

\usetheme{I6pd2} % Use the I6pd2 theme supplied with this template

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym} % For including math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

%\usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % Uncomment to use Times as the main font
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % Uncomment to use a Serif font within math environments

\boldmath % Use bold for everything within the math environment

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files

\usecaptiontemplate{\small\structure{\insertcaptionname~\insertcaptionnumber: }\insertcaption} % A fix for figure numbering

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\huge Student Attitudes and the Value of Foundation Degree Police Pre-Join Routes: An Investigation} % Poster title

\author{\textbf{Sean Butcher and Stuart Norton}} % Author(s)

\institute{Institute of Professional Policing

\textit{Buckinghamshire New University}} % Institution(s)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FOOTER TEXT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\leftfoot}{POLCON 5, Teeside University} % Left footer text

\newcommand{\rightfoot}{September 2014} % Right footer text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of two major columns, each of which can be subdivided further with another \begin{columns} block - the [t] argument aligns each column's content to the top

\begin{column}{.02\textwidth}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{.465\textwidth} % The first column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
\item The manifestation of a broad and significant police reform agenda (see Home Office, 2010) has both directly and indirectly presented opportunity for police organisations and education providers to define and design supplementary and additional routes in training and entry into the police service. One example of the recent diversification of pre-entry programmes is the development of the FdA Policing programme at Bucks New University, which has been designed in partnership with Thames Valley Police (TVP) to serve as a form of pre-entry into the service.
\item This poster presents the aims and initial findings of an associated project, designed as an exploratory and descriptive analysis of the candidate response to the programme. Specifically, the poster presents selected findings from a monitoring and mapping exercise of a specific candidate cohort.
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{References}

\begin{itemize}
\item Home Office (2010) \textit{Policing in the 21st Century: Reconnecting Police and the People}. London: HMSO.
\item Neyroud, P. (2011) \textit{Review of Police Leadership and Training: Volume One}. London: Home Office.
\item Punch, M. (2007) 'Cops with Honours: University Education and Police Culture', in O'Neill, M. Marks, M. Singh, A.M. (eds.) \textit{Police Occupational Culture}. Amsterdam: Elsveier.
\item Reiner, R. (2010) \textit{The Politics of the Police} (4th edn). Oxford: OUP.
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the second column

\begin{column}{.015\textwidth}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange.   You will need to provide some code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: That code is a little help - but what we really need is a complete MWE (minimum (non)working example) - the shortest compilable document that illustrates the problem. PS I used indentation to format your embedded code.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I'm not entirely sure what a complete MWE is (I'm a bit of a novice at this kind of stuff!). Would you mind if I sent you a URL for the document, so you can see the code in better context? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: A MWE is a compilable document (or one that almost compiles, with just the error that needs fixing). It should start with a document class, use only the necessary packages and then provide minimal code between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. That will help us zero in on your problem. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?lq=1

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I've had a look at the resources that you've sent but am still a little confused. I've pasted what I believe to be sufficient into the original post. The problem is the differentiation between the INTRODUCTION and the REFERENCES block - within the introduction block the bullet points fall within the block, but in the references block they fall outside. There does appear to be no difference in the code though...

Comment: You're getting there. This document compiles correctly and does not show the formatting error _if I comment out the `\usetheme{I6pd2}`_. I don't have that theme's source. Googling for I6pd2 yields some links that might help you. So might someone else on this site, now that you've provided enough context.